# How to change favicon right align inside the browser address bar

Tags: html, browser, favicon

I'm facing this problem and don't know how to change my image-icon address to be displayed with right align?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"  href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

Updated to be like this one, but there is no change

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"  href="/favicon.ico" style="text-align: right;"/>
```

Comment: So you want your icon to appear on the right side of address bar?

Comment: No - the style attribute is not available for link tags http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

Comment: That's impossible. Forget it.

Comment: Thx, but is there any explanation why this is not possible ?

Comment: Where to display the icon is part of your browser's design.
Since you cannot change how the browser looks, this is impossible.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this as style attribute is not available in link tag. Moreover you just can't change the browser look and feel unless they change its look and feel and move the icon to the right.